# Finding a joint log likelihood function given some data and a probability model

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, likelihood

I am reviewing some notes on binary data analysis and encountered the following problem Let $y=(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $x=(0.9, 1.2, 0.5, 1, -0.3, -1.5, -2)$. I make the assumption that $y_i$ ~ $Bin(1, \pi_i)$ and $logit(\pi_i)=x_i\beta$.

How do I draw the join log likelihood function of $y$ (as a function of $\beta$).

Comment: This sounds like a [tag:self-study] question. Try looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). Then if you are still stuck, you can [update the question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to show what you have done so far, and where the remaining issue is (specifically).

Answer (score 1):

Let's first write down the likelihood function for a $Binomial(1, \pi_i)$ (which by the way is a $Bernoulli(\pi_i)$):

$$L(y_i|\pi_i) = \pi_i^{y_i}(1-\pi_i)^{1-y_i}$$

Notes:

1. How can you generalize this for $L(\bf{y}|\pi)$ where $\bf{y}$ is a vector representing all of your observations?
2. Then what happens when you take the log of that function?
3. You're using a logit link function, namely $logit(\pi_i) = x_i\beta$. What does that make $\pi_i$ in terms of $\beta$? It shouldn't require too much algebra to plug-in this value for $\pi_i$ in your log-likelihood.
4. To actually "draw" it, I assume you want to make a plot with $\beta$ on the x-axis and $L(y|\beta)$ on the y-axis. That's now a programming question that we can help you with when you get there.

Give that a shot and let us know if you have more questions.